# How to export an extended class without curly brackets? (Node JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, import, export

My goal is to export an extended class called `Entrance` without using curly brackets (Let's say `subclass`).

The problem is I can't access to the `subclass` while I'm using `default` keyword on it and the browser gives me an error such as this:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Duplicate export of 'default'

Code:

```
// terminal.js
export default class Terminal {
    constructor(output) {
        this.output = output;
        console.log(`This is Terminal`);
    }
}
export default class Entrance extends Terminal {
    constructor(output) {
        super(output);
    }
    ticket() {
        console.log(`Ticket please`);
    }
}

// human.js
import Entrance from './terminal.js';
class People {
    constructor(name, input) {
        this.name = name;
        this.input = new Entrance(this);
        this.input.ticket();
    }
}
const guy = new People('james');
```

Is this type of structure doesn't allow originally? Or did I miss something in the code?

Thanks for listening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adapted your project to Node.js because this is easier for testing. In the browser you can still use the .js extension but you need to reference the files as modules, not as scripts.

For Node.js use the extension .mjs for ECMAScript Modules ('import' and 'export' are a feature of ECMAScript modules).
You only need to export the identifiers you reference externally: (the 'Entrance' class).

Use 'node --experimental-modules ./human.mjs' to run it

```
// terminal.mjs: only 'Entrance' is exported
// no need to export 'Terminal' as long as it's name is not referenced outside
class Terminal {
    constructor(output) {
        this.output = output;
        console.log(`This is Terminal`);
    }
}
export default class Entrance extends Terminal {
    constructor(output) {
        super(output);
    }
    ticket() {
        console.log(`Ticket please`);
    }
}

// human.mjs
import Entrance from './terminal.mjs';
class People {
    constructor(name, output) {
        this.name = name;
        this.input = new Entrance(this);
        this.input.ticket();
    }
}
const guy = new People('james');
```

If you want to reference also the Terminal class outside, dont use 'default' exports/imports (or create a top level object with Terminal and Entrance as members):

```
// terminal2.mjs
export class Terminal {
    constructor(output) {
        this.output = output;
        console.log(`This is Terminal`);
    }
}
export class Entrance extends Terminal {
    constructor(output) {
        super(output);
    }
    ticket() {
        console.log(`Ticket please`);
    }
}

// human2.mjs: import the whole module under the alias 'term'
import * as term from './terminal2.mjs';
class People {
    constructor(name, output) {
        this.name = name;
        this.input = new term.Entrance(this);
        this.input.ticket();
        new term.Terminal(this);
    }
}

// human3.mjs: using named imports which are directly usable
import { Terminal, Entrance} from './terminal2.mjs';
class People {
    constructor(name, output) {
        this.name = name;
        this.input = new Entrance(this);
        this.input.ticket();
        new Terminal(this);
    }
}
const guy = new People('james');
```

Now with default exports but encapsulated into a library object. This might be the standard way to do it, but only export the symbols you reference outside:

```
// terminal4.mjs: using a top level object and a default export
class Terminal {
    constructor(output) {
        this.output = output;
        console.log(`This is Terminal`);
    }
}
class Entrance extends Terminal {
    constructor(output) {
        super(output);
    }
    ticket() {
        console.log(`Ticket please`);
    }
}
const myLib = {Terminal, Entrance};
export default myLib;
// or just: export default {Terminal, Entrance};'

// human4.mjs
import term from './terminal4.mjs';
class People {
    constructor(name, output) {
        this.name = name;
        this.input = new term.Entrance(this);
        this.input.ticket();
        new term.Terminal(this);
    }
}
const guy = new People('james');
```

references:

- 'export': https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export
- 'import': https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import
- Node.js ECMAScript Modules: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question, but is that keyword `term` some kind of magic value such as `default value`, `event` or `e` in JS? or just a normal word? Using `.mjs` type and `*` is totally new experiences for me so I want to know more clearer even if it's a tiny thing.

Comment: 'term' is not a keyword, it is just a randomly chosen identifier, you can use any name here.

Answer (score 1):

The error is shown because you are exporting both Terminal and Entrance classes as default.

if you need only Entrance class from terminal.js, remove `export default` from Terminal class.

Comment: This works but are there no ways to import the classes more than 3 without curly brackets?

Comment: Only one default export is allowed per file. so, you have to import others through curly brackets. more details here: https://javascript.info/import-export